# Debug the Fruit Into Baskets problem in Javascript using Map Object

Tags: javascript, object, debugging, hashmap

I am getting stuck in below coding problem. It seems like there is a bug in Map.prototype.entries(), however I would like to have your expert comments on this

Question meaning: What is the length of longest subarray that contains up to two distinct integers?

Here is the problem statement , it's a LC problem

> You are visiting a farm that has a single row of fruit trees arranged from left to right. The trees are represented by an integer array fruits where fruits[i] is the type of fruit the ith tree produces.
>
> You want to collect as much fruit as possible. However, the owner has
> some strict rules that you must follow:
>
> You only have two baskets, and each basket can only hold a single type
> of fruit. There is no limit on the amount of fruit each basket can
> hold. Starting from any tree of your choice, you must pick exactly one
> fruit from every tree (including the start tree) while moving to the
> right. The picked fruits must fit in one of your baskets. Once you
> reach a tree with fruit that cannot fit in your baskets, you must
> stop. Given the integer array fruits, return the maximum number of
> fruits you can pick.

Below is my code

```js
var totalFruit = function(fruits) {
        // create a map  of fruit type
        var fruitTypes = new Map();
        var fruitCount = 0;
        var maxFruits = 0;
        // iterate till end
        for(var indx=0; indx<fruits.length; indx++)
        {
            console.log('\nI am at index:'+indx+' now and value is:'+fruits[indx]);
            // add only 2 types of fruit
            if(fruitTypes.size <=2)
            {   
                
                fruitTypes.set(fruits[indx], ++fruitCount);
                maxFruits = fruitCount;
                console.log('\n maxFruit count is '+maxFruits);

            }

            // if the type of fruit is more than two
            if(fruitTypes.size > 2)
            {
                const iterator1 = fruitTypes.entries();

console.log(iterator1.next().value);
// expected output: ["0", "foo"]
                                // now remove the first set of fruit 
                console.log('\nfruittype size  is: '+ fruitTypes.size+' and fruit count is: '+fruitCount);
                const key = fruitTypes.keys();
                var keyToDelete = key.next().value;
                const value = fruitTypes.values();
                var valueToSubtract = value.next().value;

                
                console.log('Deleting fruit type: '+keyToDelete+ ' and substracting number of fruits='+valueToSubtract);
                fruitTypes.delete(keyToDelete);
                fruitCount = fruitCount - valueToSubtract;
                console.log('\nfruittype size now is: '+ fruitTypes.size+' and fruit count is: '+fruitCount);
            }

        }
        console.log("\nmaxFruits="+maxFruits+", fruitcount="+fruitCount);
        return Math.max(maxFruits,  fruitCount);
};

var fruits = [3,3,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,3,4];

console.log('\nmaximum fruit count='+totalFruit(fruits));
```

The code is working fine but failing for the given test case, i.e.

**Input:
[3,3,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,3,4]
Output:
4
Expected:
5**

Can someone point help troubleshooting where I did the mistake?

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect 5.  You pick 3,3,3 in first basket.  Then it switches to fruit 1, so you pick 1 in your 2nd basket, then it switches to fruit 2 and you cannot pick anymore fruit.  So it should be 4 total.

Comment: Ahh.. actually i think i understand.  You can start at any tree for EACH basket

Comment: The question means: What is the length of longest subarray that contains up to two distinct integers?

Comment: Actually it means what are the 2 longest subarrays with identical integers

Answer (score 1):

- You need to keep track of the `maxFruits` while iterating - don't unconditionally overwrite it with `maxFruits = fruitCount`, instead call `maxFruits = Math.max(fruitCount, maxFruits);`. Otherwise, a possibly higher prior record may be lost.
- With `fruitTypes.set(fruits[indx], ++fruitCount);`, you're not adding the right value - you should be adding to the *current value at that index* in the Map. For example, given `[1, 2, 2]`, after the third iteration, you'd want the Map to contain

```
1 => 1,
2 => 2
```

and not

```
1 => 1
2 => 3
```

because there are two elements of type 2, not three.

But I don't think this approach is the right one, since it'd be a bit ugly to identify how many items to subtract when encountering a new time. For example, with

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
```

when iterating over the 3, you'd need to be able to identify that you need to remove both the 1 (index 0) and the 2 (index 1) - summing up to 2, while leaving the rest. The earliest key in the Map isn't necessarily the one to delete, either, as you can see by the above example.

This is how I'd do it - keep track of both the number of single consecutive types up to the current iteration (eg `[3, 3, 3]` -> size 3) and also the number of two-consecutive types up to the current iteration (eg `[4, 3, 3, 3]` -> size 4). When a different type is found, assign the single-consecutive to the two-consecutive, and take the maximum of two-consecutives found over all iterations.

```js
const calculateFruits = (fruitTypes) => [...fruitTypes.values()].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
var totalFruit = function(fruits) {
  let consecutiveIdentical = 0;
  let consecutiveOfTwoTypes = 0;
  let currentType;
  let currentTypes = [];
  let maxFruitsSoFar = 0;
  for (const type of fruits) {
    if (!currentTypes.includes(type)) {
      consecutiveOfTwoTypes = consecutiveIdentical;
      if (currentTypes.length === 2) {
        currentTypes = [currentType, type];
        consecutiveOfTwoTypes = consecutiveIdentical;
      } else {
        currentTypes.push(type);
      }
    }
    consecutiveOfTwoTypes++;
    if (currentType !== type) {
      consecutiveIdentical = 1;
    } else {
      consecutiveIdentical++;
    }
    currentType = type;
    maxFruitsSoFar = Math.max(maxFruitsSoFar, consecutiveOfTwoTypes);
  }
  return maxFruitsSoFar;
}
var fruits = [33, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

console.log('maximum fruit count=' + totalFruit(fruits));
```

Comment: This does not work for this input: `[3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] // = 8`

Answer (score 1):

This is not all fancy written in 1 line of code or anything, but it works well.  You can event specify more baskets:

```js
var totalFruit = function(fruits) {
  // create a map  of fruit type
  const nBASKETS = 2;
  let nTotalFruit = 0;
  let cur_fruit = 0;
  let nCurLongest = 0;
  let nCurFruitCnt = 0;
  let nBeginIdx = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < nBASKETS; i++ )
    // find longest sub-array, record its size, then remove it
    for(var indx=0; indx<fruits.length; indx++){
      if(indx)
        if(fruits[indx] == cur_fruit)
          nCurFruitCnt ++
        else {
          if(nCurFruitCnt > nCurLongest){
            nCurLongest = nCurFruitCnt;
            nBeginIdx = indx - nCurFruitCnt
          }
          nCurFruitCnt = 1;
          cur_fruit = fruits[indx]
        }
      else{ // left boundary
       cur_fruit = fruits[indx];
       nCurFruitCnt = 1;
       nCurLongest = 1;
       nBeginIdx = 0
      }

      if(indx == fruits.length - 1){ // right boundary
        if(nCurFruitCnt > nCurLongest){
            nCurLongest = nCurFruitCnt;
          nBeginIdx = indx - nCurFruitCnt
        }
            
        // processed array... remove longest sub-array
        nTotalFruit += nCurLongest;
        fruits.splice(nBeginIdx, nCurLongest)
      }
    }
  return nTotalFruit
}
var fruits = [3,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,3];

console.log('\nmaximum fruit count = '+totalFruit(fruits));
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first, **I make a copy of fruit types**,

*Then* for different fruits, **I check the chaining data in a row**

```
const calculate = (fruits) => {
  const typeOfFruits = [...(new Set(fruits))];
  let total = 0;

  typeOfFruits.forEach(f => {
    let NumberOfFruit = 0;
    let chain = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
      if (!(!!NumberOfFruit)) {
        if (fruits[i] === f && fruits[i + 1] === f) {
          NumberOfFruit += 1;
          chain = true;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (chain) {
          if (fruits[i] === f) NumberOfFruit += 1;
          else chain = false;
        }
      }
    }
    total += NumberOfFruit;
  });

    return total;
}

calculate([3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]); // 5
```

Comment: This is not working for this input: `calculate([3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]); // 6`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var totalFruit = function(fruits) {

    if(fruits.length <=2)
    {
        console.log("no point going forward, since the length is "+fruits.length);
        
        return fruits.length;
    } else {

    // create a map  of fruit type
    var fruitTypes = new Map();
    
    var maxFruits = 0;
    var prevKey = 0;
    var lastTwoConsequtiveValues = 0;
    // iterate till end
    for(var indx=0; indx<fruits.length; indx++)
    {
        //console.log('\nI am at index:'+indx+' now and value is:'+fruits[indx]);
        // add only 2 types of fruit
        if(fruitTypes.size <=2)
        {   
            
            
            var keyFruit = fruits[indx];
            fruitTypes.set(keyFruit, fruitTypes.get(keyFruit) == undefined ? 1 : fruitTypes.get(keyFruit) + 1)
            
            
            //if(fruitTypes.size >= 2){
            console.log("\n******************");    
            console.log([...fruitTypes.entries()]);
            var values = fruitTypes.values();
            var val1 = values.next().value;    
            if(val1 == undefined)
                val1 = 0;      
            var val2 = values.next().value;          
            if(val2 == undefined)
                val2 = 0;
            // before deleting store the fruit value
            console.log('\nval1='+val1+' val2='+val2);
            lastTwoConsequtiveValues = val1 + val2;
            console.log('\n 1. lastTwoConsequtiveValues ='+lastTwoConsequtiveValues);
            maxFruits = Math.max(maxFruits,  lastTwoConsequtiveValues);
            console.log('\n 1. Maximum value is '+maxFruits);
            console.log([...fruitTypes.entries()]);
            console.log("\n+++++++++++++");
            //}
        }

        // if the type of fruit is more than two
        if(fruitTypes.size > 2)
        {
            

            console.log('\nfruittype size  is: '+ fruitTypes.size);
           
            //if(fruitTypes.size >= 2){
                      
                
                var values = fruitTypes.values();
                var val1 = values.next().value;          
                var val2 = values.next().value;    
                if(val1 == undefined)
                    val1 = 0;      
                if(val2 == undefined)
                    val2 = 0;          
                // before deleting store the fruit value
                console.log('\nval1='+val1+' val2='+val2);
                lastTwoConsequtiveValues = val1 + val2;
                console.log('\n 2. lastTwoConsequtiveValues ='+lastTwoConsequtiveValues);
                maxFruits = Math.max(maxFruits,  lastTwoConsequtiveValues);
                console.log('\n 2. Maximum value is '+maxFruits);
               // }
            // now delete the first key
            var keys = fruitTypes.keys()
            keyToDelete = keys.next().value;   
            console.log('\nDeleting deleteFirstKey fruit type: '+keyToDelete);
            fruitTypes.delete(keyToDelete);
            console.log([...fruitTypes.entries()]);
            
        }

    }
    console.log("\nmaxFruits="+maxFruits);
    return maxFruits;
}
};
```